# Selecting records based upon conditions on multiple associations that use the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have what is actually a common situation in Rails where I have a model that has two associations. I want to be able to search for specific records defined by the model based upon conditions on either one or both of these associations.

The twist is that these two associations use the same table.

Here's the main model:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :primary_item, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: 'primary_item_Id'
  belongs_to :secondary_item, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: 'secondary_item_Id'
  ...
```

And the `Item` model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :res_primary, class_name: 'Resource', foreign_key: 'primary_item_Id'
  has_many :res_secondary, class_name: 'Resource', foreign_key: 'secondary_item_Id'
  ...
```

Let's suppose an `Item` has a string field called `name`. It's just the name of the item. I want to be able to find all of the resources that have a primary and/or secondary item that is like a given name. Here's what that looks like (I think) if I am just filtering for a primary item:

```
@resources.joins(:primary_item)
          .where("#{Item.table_name}.name like #{primary_search_string}")
```

The `primary_search_string` is just the string I want to match in the `name`. This works fine. A similar search works for the secondary items.

Now suppose I'd like the user to be able to search for resources that have either a given primary item name, a given secondary item by name, or both (each with its own name). I would have a `primary_search_string` and a `secondary_search_string` with independent values. One of them could be `nil` which would mean I don't want to narrow the search based upon that string. What I want is to filter the resources by either or both strings depending upon whether they are `nil`. Here is what I ended up with which works but seems awkward:

```
@resources = <some query that obtains an active record relation of resources>

if primary_search_string then
  @resources = @resources.joins(:primary_item)
                         .where("#{Item.table_name}.name like #{primary_search_string}")
  if secondary_search_string then
    @resources = @resources.joins(:secondary_item)
                           .where("secondary_items_#{Item.table_name}.name like #{secondary_search_string}")
  end
elsif secondary_search_string then
  @resources = @resources.joins(:secondary_item)
                        .where("#{Item.table_name}.name like #{secondary_search_string}")
end
```

Note how that if I am only joining one table, the table's name is known by `Item.table_name`. However, if I have to join both tables, then Rails must distinguish the second instance of the table by specifying the name further with the association name: `secondary_items_#{Item.table_name}`.

My question is whether there's a somewhat simpler way of handling this that doesn't involve having to reference the table names of the associations in the `where` clauses? Since I am referencing the table names of the associations, and the table name may be different depending upon whether I'm joining one of them or both of them, I end up checking the search string for `nil`, which is a way to determine whether I'm joining the `Item` table more than once. In this particular program example, I can check for it and live with it being awkward. But what if I didn't know whether `@resources` was previously joined to the primary items and I wanted to filter based upon the secondary items? I wouldn't know, in that case, what the associations table name would be to use in the `where` clause since I wouldn't know if it were already `join`ed or not.

I suspect there may be a better way here, which is the essence of my question.

Comment: I'm assuming you need two separate associations, and not just one association where a Resource could have multiple Items, and some of them could be marked as "is_primary"?

Comment: @dlehman I am working with an existing database, so I don't have the option of modifying the schema. The database has a couple of tables of this nature where a record in another table might have two items from the same associated table. I guess it would be like you had a person and maybe you had the city in which they were born, and the city in which they currently lived, and each tied to a city name table.

Answer (score -1):

If you have two separate associations, but they are both to the same type of child object (eg. Resource), then instead of joins/includes, you could just focus on finding the `Resource` records that match either the `primary_item_id` or `secondary_item_id` of the parent `Item` record you want.

Rails 3/4 doesn't natively support OR queries, but one way to brute-force it is by finding IDs of `Resources` that belong to the `Item` as a primary or secondary association. (This is obviously inefficient because you are doing multiple database queries.)

```
ids = Resource.where(primary_item_id: @item.id).map(&:id)
ids << Resource.where(secondard_item_id: @item.id).map(&:id)
@special_resources = Resource.where(id: ids, name: 'Some Special Name')
```

Rails 5 supports 'or' queries, so it's much simpler:

```
resources = Resource.where(primary_item_id: @item.id).or(secondary_item_id: @item.id)
@special_resources = resources.where(name: 'Some Special Name')
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite getting at my problem, so that tells me maybe I didn't explain it well. I'm not looking for an "or" query. A `Resource` has two different attributes: a primary item and a secondary item. These can, independently, be a particular value taken from the `Item` table. So I might want to find all the resources that have "foo" as the name of it's primary item. In another case, I might want to find all the resources with "bar" as its secondary item. In another case, I might want to find all the resources that have "foo" as the primary item, AND "bar" as the secondary.

Comment: The user may enter a search string for either primary or secondary or both. But... where I get stuck in Rails is that it's implicit table naming changes for a given table if that same table gets joined a second time.